# How can I write Bacula's bootstrap files on a remote machine?

Tags: backup, bacula

Have this in configuration of jobs:

```
JobDefs {
  Name = "DefaultJob"
  Type = Backup
  Level = Incremental
  Client = "SERVER_1" 
  FileSet = "Full Set"
  Schedule = "Month-each-day cycle at 21:00"
  Storage = "ubuntu-station"
  Messages = Standard
  Pool = Default
  Priority = 10

  Write Bootstrap = "/var/lib/bacula/%c.bsr"
}
```

And it's ok, but it saves bootstrap files on the same machine I run Bacula server.
Can I specify a Client to save bootstrap files right with the backup archives? (I didn't find how to do it)
Or how it is better done?

**Edit:**
My backups are going here:

```
Client {
  Name = "ubuntu-station"
  Address = ip (it's other machine)
  FDPort = 9102
  Catalog = MyCatalog
  Password = ""
  File Retention = 90 days
  Job Retention = 6 months
  AutoPrune = yes
}
```

I have full access to it, but it's not always up. (So I can't use NFS, can I? try to mount it each time? Will Bacula hang if can't mount it?)

Isn't there an option to save bootstrap files to specific Client? Or only use NFS?

Comment: Where are your backup files going?  What kind of access do you have to the remote machine?  If NFS, then it should be easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot save Bacula bootstraps to a client.  Theoretically you would never want to do this.

The purpose of a bootstrap record is to allow you to restore specific data without having to re-scan entire tapes.  The bootstrap record should be stored with the backup media (on the storage daemon if you're backing up to disk) or shipped off-site with the tapes (email it to a gmail account, burn it to a CD and ship it with the tape box, etc.)

If you put your bootstrap on the client and then you lose your environment (client, or both client and server) the bootstrap is gone too, and you will need to scan all the tapes since your last Full backup to determine what to restore.

---

Having said that, you *can* copy the bootstraps to the client if you *really* want to, using a `RunAfterJob` or `ClientRunAfterJob` directive in the Job resource.  Simply have the client download the `.bsr` file (or have the server upload it to the client) when the job is finished running.